# For NetworkX, can I have both directed and undirected edges in a multidigraph?

Tags: networkx, graph-theory

For a coding problem, I need to create a graph between Elements of two sets, A and B. Elements of A are related to all other members of A (complete graph); the edge between i and j is the same as the edge between j and i for all i,j in A. Elements of set A have a directed edge to all members of set B. These edges can take any real number value. I anticipate I will need to use the MultiDiGraph for this application, but is there a way I can avoid constructing multiple edges between elements of set A since it is effectively the complete graph of A? I am concerned about runtime and would like to keep the construction as a simple as possible

I have yet to try the MultiDigraph since I want to ensure it is the best type to use!

Comment: Just use a digraph, but include edges both from i to j and from j to i. This is not considered "multiple edges" in the sense that would require the multidigraph type.